# How can I get user history between two dates with deezer API?

Tags: deezer

I would like to get user history between two dates (get history for one month for example). Is there a way to add param in url ? something like :

> http://api.deezer.com/user/me/history?start=1483522674&end=1483609074

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, but instead you can use the "limit" and "index" parameters.